Find constants $p$, $q$, and $r$ for $\frac{16x+1}{px+1} > x+4$ where solution set is $x < q$ or $r < x < 3$

Find constants $p$, $q$, and $r$ for
$$ 
\frac{16x+1}{px+1} > x+4
$$
where solution set is $x < q$ or $r < x < 3$.

Attempted to rearrange for quadratic, but resulted in range of values for $p$. After this, I attempted to draw a graph where $p$ is positive then again for when $p$ is negative; however, this didn't help as I only find the expressions for constants in terms of $p$. Could someone attempt to walk through this question?

For what it's worth, virtually no MathSE posted question that I have seen (from me or anyone else) that followed
this article on MathSE protocol
has been downvoted. Instead, such questions are almost always upvoted, with
MathSE reviewers going out of their way to try to answer the question.

Hint: for $~x \neq \dfrac{-1}{16},~$ how would you evaluate $~\dfrac{16x + 1}{4x + (1/4)} ~?$

I had to downvote this. It is very hard to follow with little effort shown to make this clear for the reader or to show work [a lot like the OP's other questions]. I feel the OP could have done a better job writing this up. As far as the ecology of this site is concerned we cannot be encouraging these types of questions going forward, as they do not add value

@Mike, thank you for your response. I agree that my questions have been subpar relative to other questions and what is expected. Further details will be provided in future with working and the specific problems at hand. Kindly, Harvey.

That is wonderful and that is all we can ask for. Thank you @Hooman .

I'm not very sure, but this is supposed to work.
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{16x+1}{px+1}>x+4 \\
\implies \frac{16x+1}{px+1}-(x+4)>0 \\
\implies \frac{16x+1-x^2p-x-4px-4}{px+1}>0 \\
\implies \frac{x^2p+(4p-15)x+3}{px+1}<0 \\
\end{align*}$$
Now we apply quadratic formula for the numerator to get it's roots. We get
$$x=\frac{-4p+15±\sqrt{16p^2+225-132p}}{2p}=k_1,k_2,k_2<k_1$$
The following few steps can be skipped and be done in a single line. But for the sake of explanation.
So $$\begin{align*}
\frac{(x-k_1)(x-k_2)}{px+1}<0 \\
\implies \frac{(x-k_1)(x-k_2)(px+1)}{(px+1)^2}<0 \\
\implies (x-k_1)(x-k_2)(px+1)<0 \\
\implies (x-k_1)(x-k_2)(x+\frac{1}{p})<0 \end{align*}$$
Now the solution set can be represented as $x<q,r<x<3$ which corresponds to the solution set for the inequality $(x-q)(x-r)(x-3)<0$,where $q<r$.(By method of intervals).(I will link an explanation to it below).
Validity of the value of p.
We had a quad function w.r.t $x$, where the discriminant was in the form of $p$. The discriminant must not be negative, so
$$16p^2+225-132p≥0$$
This gives us a range of $p$.
$$p \in \bigg(-∞, \frac{1}{8}(33 - 3 \sqrt{21})\bigg] \cup \bigg[\frac{1}{8} (33 + 3 \sqrt{21}), ∞\bigg)$$
This is the reason why I cannot compare $(x-k_2)$ with $(x-3)$, as $k_2=3$ will have no real solutions with $p$.
By direct comparison, $$\frac{1}{p}=-3 \implies p=\frac{-1}{3}$$
Or
$$k_1=3 \implies 3=\frac{-4p+15+\sqrt{16p^2+225-132p}}{2p}\\
\implies (10p-15)^2=16p^2+225-132p$$
$$\implies p=2$$ (We can't take $p=0$)
This gives us corresponding values for $k_1,k_2$, numerically
$$k_1=\frac{1}{2}(-49+\sqrt{2437}),3\\
k_2=\frac{1}{2}(-49-\sqrt{2437}),\frac{1}{2}$$
Equations:-
$$x<\frac{1}{2}(-49-\sqrt{2437}) \ \text{or} \ \frac{1}{2}(-49+\sqrt{2437})<x<3 $$
Or
$$x<\frac{-1}{2} \ \text{or} \ \frac{1}{2}<x<3$$
Hence $$p=\frac{-1}{3},q=\frac{1}{2}(-49-\sqrt{2437}), r=\frac{1}{2}(-49+\sqrt{2437}) \\$$ or $$
p=2,q=\frac{-1}{2},r=\frac{1}{2}$$

About method of intervals

This is a fantastic answer and covers everything that I struggled in. Thank you so much for you response.

You're so welcome. Are these the actual answers? Or are their more? I thought there were more actually ;)

These were in fact the correct answers, thank you for introducing me to the method of intervals, it will eb very helpful in the future.

:) It's alright. There's actually lot more to it. If you're interested, you can also learn wavy curve method, which is very useful. Its kind of a quick version of method of intervals

Also, for when you found expressions for $k_1$ and $k_2$,I can't seem to wrap my head around where $\frac{1}{2} (-49±\sqrt{2437})$ came from, could you explain?

Putting $p=\frac{-1}{3}$ inside $x=\frac{-4p+15±\sqrt{16p^2+225-132p}}{2p}=k_1,k_2,k_2<k_1$
